# How to specify alignment for global device variables in CUDA

Tags: cuda, nvcc

I would like to declare the alignment for a global device variable in CUDA. Specifically, I have a string declaration, like 
    `__device__ char str1 = "some pre-defined string";`
In normal gcc, I can request alignment from the compiler as
    `__device__ char str1 __attribute__ ((aligned (4))) = "some pre-defined string";`

However, when I tried this on nvcc, the compiler ignores these requests. The reason I would like to do this is to copy these strings onto a buffer in my kernels, and copying words at a time is much faster than copying bytes at a time, though they require that the src string be aligned. Can anyone please tell me how to request alignment from the nvcc compiler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See section 5.3.2 "Size and Alignment Requirement" of the "CUDA C Programming Guide", which can be found [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html):

The alignment requirement is automatically fulfilled for the built-in types of char, short, int, long, longlong, float, double like float2 or float4.

For structs, the size and alignment requirements can be enforced by the compiler using the alignment specifiers `__align__(8)` or `__align__(16)`.

Example usage:

```
struct __align__(8) { 
    float r; 
    float i;
} complex_num;
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. I checked the NVCC compiler guide looking for something mentioned there. I should have checked the C programming guide as well.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if this works?

```
__device__ char __align__(4) str1 = "some pre-defined string";
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This was my first time asking for help on StackOverflow, and I will definitely use it as a resource in the future.